# Find a solution to the following ordinary differential equation : $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{x−y}(e^x−e^y).$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find a solution to the following ordinary differential equation - $$\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{x−y}(e^x−e^y).$$

A change of variables so that it becomes variable separable may be required.

Comment: Hint: Let $z = e^y$ and $\omega = e^x$ then $\frac{dz}{d\omega} = \omega - z$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the change of variables $z = e^y$ and $\omega = e^x$ the ODE becomes

$$\frac{dz}{d\omega} = \omega - z \implies \frac{d}{d\omega}\left(e^{\omega} z\right) = \omega e^{\omega}$$

which gives the solution

$$z = e^{-\omega}\int\omega' e^{\omega'}d\omega' = (\omega-1) + Ce^{-\omega}$$

or in terms of the original variables

$$y(x) = \log\left(e^x - 1 + C\exp(-e^x)\right)$$

where the integration constant $C$ can be written $C = e^{y(0) + 1}$.

Comment: good result! you may change $e^{- e^x}$ to $\exp(- e^x)$ for better formatting.